# Invoking tests on iPhone from Windows OS using Remote Server

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, appium, appium-ios

I've recently started working with Appium. Have automated a flow on Android device and successfully run on the device. Have tried the same with iOS where the tests were invoked from Mac. The document on appium states as following

> "Appium on OS X supports iOS and Android testing but from Windows we
>   can only test Android."

My question is, has anyone tried invoking the tests on iOS platform from OS other than Mac OS X like Windows or Linux?.

For example, using a Remote Server from Windows OS to connect to an Appium server running on Mac.

Or as usual do iPhones remain incompatible with anyone other than Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can automate iOS devices using appium from windows platform

all you have to do is run your appium server in MAC with your ipv4 address..

then execute your automation script from windows to that ip address..

make sure that ip address is pingable from windows platform...

In this way you can actually use c# for automation script to automate iOS platform